# Trying to iterate through a directory pre-word2vec model training

Tags: python, unicode, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to iterate through a directory as a first step of my model training. I've used this same code in the Hathi Trust environment but it's not working on my computer. Any idea of why?

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordTokenizer
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os
import gensim
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

base_dir = "redacting directory name for the purposes of this question"
all_docs = []
docs = os.listdir(base_dir)

for doc in docs:
    if not doc.startswith('.'):
        with open(base_dir + doc, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            text = file.read()
            all_docs.append(text)

len(all_docs)
```

When I run the last for loop, I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 5
      3     if not doc.startswith('.'):
      4         with open(base_dir + doc, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
----> 5             text = file.read()
      6             all_docs.append(text)
      8 len(all_docs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py:322, in BufferedIncrementalDecoder.decode(self, input, final)
    319 def decode(self, input, final=False):
    320     # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321     data = self.buffer + input
--> 322     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323     # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324     self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 78: invalid start byte
```

I've tried making sure all the files are encoded in utf-8

Comment: Read the error message twice: it says that your file isn't `utf-8` encoded. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (sanitized if necessary) some characters around (and including) the position 78 in your file. Provide a hexadecimal dump if possible…

Comment: That the problem happens so early in the file – just 78 bytes in! – may make it easy to understand what's gone wrong, once you take note of & directly-examine the exact file affected, perhaps by printing each filename from your loop before trying to read it. (And even if still perplexed, the 1st ~100 bytes of the file may be shareable to request more help from others.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. For some reason there was an rtf file in the folder that I could see through terminal but not when I looked in the file folder. That one was causing the trouble!